# Send a list of base64 encoded images using jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, xmlhttprequest

when I send my ajax request to node.js server, the parameter that contains my list of images does not appear. ( I modified the request to be 50mb on server)
This is my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
                url: '/post_vehicle',
                type: "POST",
                traditional: true,
                data: {
                    images: list,   // here is the problem, this var does not arrive on the server
                    brand: $('.post_brand :selected').text(),
                    model: $('.post_mark :selected').text(),
                    location: $('.post_location :selected').text(),
                    year: $('.post_year :selected').text(),
                    fuel_type: $('post_fuel_type :selected').text(),
                }
            })
```

I used console.log before the ajax to check that the list has images, and it displays me all the images.

This is the value of the list in the ajax:
[List value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHcTJ.png)

Comment: The server code?

Comment: The problem is that when i check the console in network section, there is no image list, just the other values, I think the  root cause for this problem is that my variable called list is not a string and ajax doesn't send it to the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on saving the images as base64 and instead, i used FormData like this:

```
let formData = new FormData($('#sell_form')[0]); 
// #sell_form is the form id where i have all the data that i need.
//Now formData variable will contain all the values from your form inputs
```

The Ajax Request

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/post_vehicle',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            dataType:'json',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
        });
```

If you want to add extra data

```
formData.append("Key",'Value');
```